# How can I use gsub in a user-supplied input to xtable's sanitize.text.function argument?

Tags: r, gsub, xtable

I have a table of summary statistics created in R.  Rows correspond to variables, columns to different samples.  I want to export this table to Latex using the `xtable` package.  However, some variables are on a much larger scale, so I would like to round these variables.  I have tried creating a user-supplied input to xtable's sanitize.text.function to do this:

```
dt <- data.table(sample1 = c(1.11, 2222.22), sample2 = c(3.33, 44444.44))  # data for MWE
rownames(dt) <- c('var 1', 'var 2')
xt <- print(xtable(dt),
            format.args=list(big.mark=","),
            sanitize.text.function = \(x) gsub('([0-9]+,[0-9]{3})\\.[0-9]{2}', '\\1', x)) 

# OUTPUT:
# \begin{table}[ht]
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}{rrr}
#   \hline
#  & sample1 & sample2 \\ 
#   \hline
# var 1 & 1.11 & 3.33 \\ 
#   var 2 & 2,222.22 & 44,444.44 \\ 
#    \hline
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table}
```

However the variables are not rounded in the output table as I would like them to be.  Calling the same `gsub` function on the output of the call to `xtable` works:

```
gsub('([0-9]+,[0-9]{3})\\.[0-9]{2}', '\\1', xt)
[1] "\\begin{table}[ht]\n\\centering\n\\begin{tabular}{rrr}\n  \\hline\n & sample1 & sample2 \\\\ \n  \\hline\nvar 1 & 1.11 & 3.33 \\\\ \n  var 2 & 2,222 & 44,444 \\\\ \n   \\hline\n\\end{tabular}\n\\end{table}\n"
```

So why doesn't this work directly in the call to `print.xtable`?  Having to save the output of call to `gsub` on the `xtable` object is a pain.

Bonus: I am trying this approach since, as far as I can see, `xtable` only allows me to format the number of decimal places for a whole column, rather than a whole row.  Any approach that allows me fix the number of decimal places for a row would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in @ZéLoff's answer, I would need to convert the input columns to `character` to use `sanitize.text.function`.  An alternative is to pre-process the numeric columns using `round`, `floor`, or `trunc`, depending on the desired output.  However, with no further pre-processing, the `print.xtable` output still includes trailing zeros, even if I have rounded the inputs.  One option, as suggested below, is to convert the input table to character.  However then I cannot use `big.mark` for large numbers.  Better to use the arguments to `formatC` to get the processed numeric columns looking as I want in the output table.

In this example, this looks like this:

```
dt <- data.table(sample1 = c(1.11, 2222.22), sample2 = c(3.33, 44444.44))  # data for MWE
round_cols <- c(1, 2)
dt[2, (round_cols) := lapply(.SD, round), .SDcols = round_cols]
rownames(dt) <- c('var 1', 'var 2')
xt <- print(xtable(dt),
            format.args=list(big.mark = ",",
                             drop0trailing = T),
            comment = F)
```

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 & sample1 & sample2 \\ 
  \hline
var 1 & 1.11 & 3.33 \\ 
  var 2 & 2,222 & 44,444 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sanitize.text.function` only applies to text, not numbers, so for it to work as you expect, you need to convert the columns to `character` vectors first.   But then you can't use formatting features like `big.mark`.

Also, relying on string substitution for this isn't rounding, is truncating.  You only keep the integer part of the number, e.g., "1000.999999" becomes "1000".  Personally, I'd use something like `signif`, or a more scrupulous use of `round` before passing the object to `xtable`:

```r
dt <- data.frame(sample1 = c(1.11, 2222.22), sample2 = c(3.33, 44444.44))  # data for MWE
dt[dt>1000] <- as.character(round(dt[dt>1000], 0))
rownames(dt) <- c('var 1', 'var 2')
xt <- print(xtable(dt),
            format.args=list(big.mark=","))
```

```latex
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rll}
  \hline
 & sample1 & sample2 \\
  \hline
var 1 & 1.11 & 3.33 \\
  var 2 & 2222 & 44444 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

(note that the code above does not work on `data.table`, hence me using `data.frame`).

Nevertheless, as you can see from the example above, either you let `xtable` treat everything as numbers, in order to use `big.mark`, and have it introduce decimal places, or you convert all columns to characters and have to format them yourself, prior to feeding the `data.frame` to `xtable`.  Its "all or nothing" with `xtable`.

On a slightly unrelated note, the `siunitx` LaTeX package has some options for tabular material, (including auto rounding and not adding decimal zeros to integers) that you might want to checkout.

Comment: Thanks @ZéLoff, you are right about the difference between truncating and rounding, given the magnitudes involved, the difference doesn't matter.  As I explain in my answer below, it turns out to be possible to drop the trailing zeros without converting to character.  That way one can still use `big.mark` and other inputs to `format.args`.